# How to sort NSmutableArray from one of it indexes (lat lng coordinates) in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, swift2

I'm new in swift and I'd know how to do that in php, but I'm lost with all those dictionaries and I have no idea how to do that in swift 2. I've been googling for a while and didn't found what I need.

I'm parsing a jSon and storing it's values in an NSMutableDictionary in a loop and at the end of the loop I store the NSMutableDictionary in an NSMutableArray, so at the end I have an NSMutableArray with 43 elements, and each element have about 10 keys with their values. I need to sort those 43 elements from their "distance" key and sort them descending. I don't know if that is posible with this current approach. The value of the key "distance" is an int number (meters). I don't know if to use an NSMutableDictionary inside an NSMutable Array is the correct approach to do this but I'm using it because it is possible to have string keys, and not numbers indexes, so for me it's easier to access the key "distance" than the index 8...

First I load the jSon content:

```
private func parseJson(json : NSMutableArray, tableView : UITableView){

        var c : Int = 0
        for j in json {
            var jsonValues = NSMutableDictionary()

            //Create main value
            guard let value = j.valueForKey("value")?.valueForKey("value")! else{
                continue
            }

            //Get name
            guard let Name : String = (value.valueForKey("Name")?.valueForKey("en") as? String) else {
                continue
            }
jsonValues["name"] = Name

//more code like this....

            TableData.append(Name)
            nsDict.insertObject(jsonValues, atIndex: c)

            c += 1
        }
```

this is my NSMutableArray content after being loaded:
[image]

[image]

And this is the code I have this far. Im trying to load the sorted content in a new array, but in this new array some keys are missing.

```
//Reorder Array by shop distance from user...
var sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "distance", ascending: true)
var sortedArray : NSArray = nsDict.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor])//Crashes

print(sortedArray)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The most convenient solution is to use Swift native collection types (`Array<>`, `Dictionary<>`) and the `sort` function.

Comment: can you show me an example with this case?

Comment: I have no idea what the JSON contains but try to replace `NSMutableArray` with `[[String:AnyObject]]` and `NSMutableDictionary` with `[String:AnyObject]`. Then sort the array with `array.sortInPlace {$0.distance < $1.distance }`

Comment: What do you mean to change NSMutableArray to [String : AnyObject] ??

Comment: I mean *use Swift native collection types* but that's not the correct replacement.

Comment: As I said, I'm new in swift, so I don't know what is to change NSMutableArray to [string:AnyObject] or anything related to Swift native collection, but thanks anyway

Comment: Please read the `Tour` and the first chapters of the Swift Language Guide to get an impression (and the benefit) of the language.

Comment: Maybe you should had started there... But since you didn't, I very much doubt that this is actually what I need to read.

Comment: No offense, but like in real life it's not much fun to speak a language without knowing the grammar...

Comment: Indeed, but in real life there are also priorities and at this precise moment (00:06), my priority is to solve this (easy) issue, not to spend hours to read some chapters of the swift documentation, to understand the grammary, because it will be more fun to fix my issue in three or four hours with full understanding... No offense, but I don't need anybody to recommend me any documentation, or in other words, your comments aren't helping at all

Comment: It seems that our time zones are the same :-)

Comment: As I said, useless comments. Thanks for nothing and good night ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to sort the array with this technique:

created a new class with for my array

```
import Foundation
class JsonArrayValues  {

    init(){

    }
    var name = String()
    var distance = Float()
    var lat = Float()
    var lng = Float()
    var openingTime = String()
    var country = String()
    var code = String()
    var address = String()
    var categories = String()
    var city = String()
    var type = String()
    var brands = String()





}
```

I instantiated one before the loop:

```
var jsonArrData : [JsonArrayValues] = []
```

And another one inside the loop, in which I've added the values:

```
        var c : Int = 0
        for j in json {
            var jsonValues : JsonArrayValues = JsonArrayValues()

//Get name
            guard let Name : String = (value.valueForKey("Name")?.valueForKey("en") as? String) else {
                continue
            }
            jsonValues.name = Name
//more code...
jsonArrData.append(jsonValues)

            c += 1
        }
```

And finally I've been able to call the function to reorder the array:

```
   //Reorder Array by shop distance from user...
    jsonArrData.sortInPlace({$0.distance < $1.distance})
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your first steps in any non-trivial project really should be to spend some time looking around on github for tools that simplify your problem. In this case, you'd find there are so very many tools to simplify working with JSON in Swift. I'd suggest you look at [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) and [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) particularly, although there are also many people who use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

You don't mention how you're accessing the network; you could look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). The latter also has [AlamofireJsonToObjects](https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects) to help.

I also found [JSONExport](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport) to be incredibly useful.

You'd be spending a lot less time futzing with details as in this unfortunate question and more getting on with your larger goal.

Comment: it's good to find tool but I prefer learn first and then use tools